# how can we run database event in seconds

Tags: mysql, events, seconds

I have added event but it's run only in a minute. Kindly let me know how can I use this event to run in second as well.

Also, let me know that database events impact our application performance too slow?

```
CREATE EVENT update_vgm_job_id ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DO
UPDATE vgm_details VD JOIN vgm V ON V.id = VD.vgm_id JOIN stuffings S ON S.booking_id = V.booking_id AND S.container_no = VD.container_no
SET VD.job_id = S.job_id, VD.stuffing_id = IF(VD.stuffing_id = 0, S.id, VD.stuffing_id) where VD.job_id = 0;
```

Comment: 'Kindly let me know how can I use this event to run in second as well.' - do you mean n minutes n seconds?

Comment: You mean like `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND`?

Comment: Database events impact the application the same way any other query does.

Comment: Yes, i want to run event every 15 second.